# Should I delete a question if I have found it to be silly?

Tags: support

**I am a new user**
and recently asked a question([Proving that $\int_0^\infty\sin(x)dx=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456924/proving-that-int-0-infty-sinxdx-1)) and found it to be very silly and somewhat related to ([Can a limit of an integral be moved inside the integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253696/can-a-limit-of-an-integral-be-moved-inside-the-integral)) . First I thought about deleting it but wouldn't it affect my reputation and prevent me from asking further question. I find no place where I can 'Close' the question(I think it requires more reputation) or answer my own question and show that it is related to [Can a limit of an integral be moved inside the integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253696/can-a-limit-of-an-integral-be-moved-inside-the-integral)
. Will it be ok to write the answer in the question itself

What should I do?

(excuse me for asking so many questions at once)

Comment: You've done fine in your question, here and there.  No need for deletion.  I'm not entirely clear on the reason(s) for closure. Any way, I agree with Siong Thye Goh, in their answer below.

Comment: I am not agree mentioning the word *silly*. I prefer *wrong*, if you are thinking that it isn't the best question. Good luck.

Answer (score 18):

I don't think the question is silly. I think it is alright to leave the question there as it helps others who have similar doubt as you.

There is a mechanism in place to avoid deletion of a post after an answer is being upvoted. It is an important feature as we should appreciate those who have volunteered their time to help you.

It is ok to write the answer in the question itself as an edit crediting those who have answered your doubt.